# Replacement of Javapos

Tags: opos, javapos

Presently I am using Javapos for Communicating with peripherals , is any other option available to communicate with Peripherals like Pos Printer , Pos cash drawer etc with out Javapos directly to Peripherals from Java code.

Can we Use Opos or any other option like Javapos to communicate with peripherals ?
Is opos is platform independent ? whether it will work in windows and Linux ?

Answer (score 2):

For question 1, according to the UPOS specification, there are JavaPOS, OPOS and POS .NET that you can use to control the peripherals without any knowledge of the hardware.

However, it is not necessary for peripheral's vendor to provide all of them for customers.

Therefore, you can only use the device/object service that the peripheral vendor provided unless you have the hardware programming guide.

For question 2, OPOS is tied to Windows because it is based on OLE and COM and it needs to communicate with hardware. (See Appendix A of the [UnifiedPOS specification](https://nrf.com/system/tdf/UnifiedPOS%20Version%201_14_1_20141023.pdf).)